# How can I perform the same action on all results of a label/search in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

When I search, for example, "something label:somelabel" I get 1000 results paginated by 25 (my settings). 'Select all' selects only the 25 on the current page, I would like to delete all of them (1000). How to do it? I guess I could specify a filter to perform this search, delete the messages and apply this filter, but I have many queries and making filters for all would be PITA.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should get a message at the top of the search results that reads;

> Select all conversations that match this search

[image: example here]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do your search Choose "Select: All".
2. This will cause a page-ful of your
   search results to get selected.
3. Now,
   you will see something like:

> "All 20 conversations on this page
>   are selected. Select all conversations
>   that match this search"

Click on this and you will get what you want.