# Is there a way to delete all email in Gmail that has a particular label?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gmail: how to perform action on all results of a label/search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4871/gmail-how-to-perform-action-on-all-results-of-a-label-search)

Currently I can filter email based on the label and then delete the paginated results, 20 at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. If you view all emails for a particular label, as you have done, then choose to select **All** from the drop down selector in the top left, it will select all emails on the page and also give you another link (at the top of the emails) to **Select all NNN conversations in "label"**. Click this, then [Delete] to delete the lot!