# Using filters to delete all messages that match

Tags: gmail, gmail-search, delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I perform the same action on all results of a label/search in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4871/how-can-i-perform-the-same-action-on-all-results-of-a-label-search-in-gmail)

In Gmail, I have a bunch of messages under a label that I want to delete (basically all the "unread" messages).

I can filter for and select "unread" and then delete them, but it only applies to the first 25 items and I have hundreds I want to delete.

What I'd like to do is to apply a filter, select the matches, and delete all the matches even if they're not in the top 25.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the algorithm:

1. Perform the search in your mails.
2. Go to the selection of your messages (checkbox icon with small down arrow) and choose "Select all".
3. As long as there are some other messages the GMail will prompt you with a message above your mailbox (see picture).

[image]

Just click on this message and you now can delete/move/mark as spam all these messages.

Comment: Thank you! I simply failed to see the link indicating "Select all conversations..."

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, when selecting "All", you don't get the option to select all that match. I don't know if there is another way of doing it?

Comment: **Update:** I was able to do this by using search, for `category: promotions` (which is what I wanted to delete) and then select all, and all that match.

Comment: Google removed the "select all that match" recently when used on the "older than x months" filter. They did it right after we used it to delete a bunch of messages so we didn't have to upgrade.