# Gmail Inbox Delete 400 Messages at One Time in an Efficient Way

Tags: gmail

I have 300 inbox messages and 291 spam messages in my Gmail. I need to delete all at one time and don't have time to click each message and delete them. I have 2 email account I have the same problem with both.

Comment: Are the spam messages under the spam label? Is there a way to identify the spam messages if they are in the inbox?

Comment: Closely related: [How can I perform the same action on all results of a label/search in Gmail?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/4871)

Answer (score 4):

1. From the menu bar at the top of the Gmail Inbox list, click the down-pointing arrow next to the rectangular-shaped icon and select **All** to select all of the email messages in your Inbox.
2. Uncheck the 9, or however many there are, messages that *aren't* spam, one at a time.
3. From the Gmail menu bar, click on the trash can icon to delete all of the messages that have been marked as selected by having a check mark in their checkboxes.